# Get error trying to create SQL Server Agent Job with XMLA command

Tags: sql-server, ssas, xmla, sql-server-job

I am trying to run an XMLA command that kicks off an Xevent trace as a SQL Agent Job. (below)

The command works fine in SSMS as an XMLA query.

When I try to save this step as an SSAS Command in an agent job, it throws an exception -

> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
> (Microsoft.SQLServer.Connectioninfo)
>
> The @flags parameter is not valid for a job step of type 'ANALYSISCOMMAND'. (Microsoft SQL Server,Error: 14545)

This job step can be saved as TSQL but it will return a syntax error - as it should - when I invoke it.

I have no experience creating agent jobs using xmla code.

```xml
<Create xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">    <ObjectDefinition>
      <Trace>
         <AutoRestart>true</AutoRestart>
         <ID>BostonWeekendTest</ID>
         <Name>BostonWeekendTest</Name>
         <XEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300">
            <event_session name="BostonWeekendTest" dispatchLatency="30" maxEventSize="0" maxMemory="4" memoryPartition="none" eventRetentionMode="NoEventLoss" trackCausality="true" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
               <event package="AS" name="QueryBegin" />
               <event package="AS" name="QuerySubcubeVerbose" />
               <event package="AS" name="ExecuteMDXScriptEnd" />
               <target package="package0" name="event_file">
                  <parameter name="filename" value="J:\XEvents\BostonWeekendTest.xel" />
                  <parameter name="max_file_size" value="4096" />
                  <parameter name="max_rollover_files" value="10" />
                  <parameter name="increment" value="1024" />
               </target>
            </event_session>
         </XEvent>
      </Trace>    </ObjectDefinition> </Create>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest SSMS with SQL Server agent on SQL 2019 CU 16 successfully created the job for me.  The `@flags` parameter is on sp_add_jobstep, so compare to what your SSMS is generating.

Here's the job creation script (with the path modified):

```
USE [msdb]


GO

/****** Object:  Job [xmla]    Script Date: 9/17/2022 12:10:06 PM ******/
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
SELECT @ReturnCode = 0
/****** Object:  JobCategory [[Uncategorized (Local)]]    Script Date: 9/17/2022 12:10:06 PM ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]' AND category_class=1)
BEGIN
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', @name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

END

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'xmla', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=0, 
        @notify_level_netsend=0, 
        @notify_level_page=0, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'No description available.', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name=N'OFFICE\david', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
/****** Object:  Step [a]    Script Date: 9/17/2022 12:10:06 PM ******/
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'a', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'ANALYSISCOMMAND', 
        @command=N'<Create xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">    <ObjectDefinition>
      <Trace>
         <AutoRestart>true</AutoRestart>
         <ID>BostonWeekendTest</ID>
         <Name>BostonWeekendTest</Name>
         <XEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300">
            <event_session name="BostonWeekendTest" dispatchLatency="30" maxEventSize="0" maxMemory="4" memoryPartition="none" eventRetentionMode="NoEventLoss" trackCausality="true" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
               <event package="AS" name="QueryBegin" />
               <event package="AS" name="QuerySubcubeVerbose" />
               <event package="AS" name="ExecuteMDXScriptEnd" />
               <target package="package0" name="event_file">
                  <parameter name="filename" value="c:\temp\BostonWeekendTest.xel" />
                  <parameter name="max_file_size" value="4096" />
                  <parameter name="max_rollover_files" value="10" />
                  <parameter name="increment" value="1024" />
               </target>
            </event_session>
         </XEvent>
      </Trace>    </ObjectDefinition> </Create>', 
        @server=N'office\sql2022', 
        @database_name=N'master', 
        @flags=0
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 1
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name = N'(local)'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GOTO EndSave
QuitWithRollback:
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
EndSave:
GO
```